# map strings to unique ids

Tags: string, python-2.7, unique

is there any python library that converts strings to unique ids?
for example, I have this kind of data written in txt file

```
"name", "john doe"
"age", "twenty two"
"school","xxxx"
"name", "sam x"
"age", "twenty two"
"school","yyyy"
```

and I want the output like this

```
1,55
2,44
3,77
1,56
2,44
3,78
```

I don't care about the numbers range but it must be positive.

and is there any way to retrieve the original strings from any given id?

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python dev, but it sounds like you want a kind of reversible hash.

Since you want integers, what you might do is loop through each character of a string, get the ASCII value, and concatenate those. It will have to still be a string, I think, due to leading zero needs.

You could also try simply assigning each letter of the alphabet a two digit value, then use that. So "age" might be 11 and 36 and 15 for 113615. Then you can just decode in two-character substrings. 10-99 is enough for lower and upper case and a few symbols even. You could have a single function for encoding and decoding with a quick check of the type of the argument passed (integer or string).

Be aware that Python may have a much more elegant way to do this, I'm just thinking about the overall strategy that would really work in almost any language.

Comment: thank you for your help. I think this approach may not provide a unique ids. For example, if I assigned (1 for a) and (2 for b) , This approach will give me 3 for the string ab and also 3 for the string ba which are two different strings.

Comment: It will give you unique strings if you use the two character system. ab would be 1011, ba would be 1110. However, they won't be unique in that the same string will always yield the same integer. You don't add them, you concatenate them.